# Symfony2 Form, lot of querys with a Entity type (Doctrine2)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have 3 entities: `person`, with an `ID`, `employee` and `applicant`.

Entity `person` have vars `employee` and `applicant`, and OneToOne relationship.

Employee and Applicant have a person as an `ID`, with `referencedColumnName="id"`, and a relationship OneToOne.

Fine, When I create a form with the entity `person`, to display a input select with all `applicants`, thanks to fuzzy-loading of Doctrine2 make queries to retrieve each `person`, each related candidate and related empleado, which means that a bd 2000 people are doing almost 6000 requests bd to display only the name.

If I don't print the form, no problem, but, if I put this in the view:

```
{{ form_rest(formularioEnlazarCandidato.person) }}
```

And Doctrine2 execute a lot of querys.

I'm not sure how to fix this, as to show an entity in the form will not let me do only select `per.id` and `per.name`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and they helped me - look here [Optimize DQL with double join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718608/optimize-dql-with-double-join). Basically you need [fetch join](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) in your repository - I did:

```
class ProfileRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findAll()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("p, stu, sta, pdd, pdt, pdc")
                ->from('AldenBonBundle:Profile', 'p')
                ->leftJoin('p.studies', 'stu')
                ->leftJoin('stu.statute', 'sta')
                ->leftJoin('p.disabilityDegree', 'pdd')
                ->leftJoin('p.disabilityType', 'pdt')
                ->leftJoin('p.disabilityCode', 'pdc')
                ->orderBy('p.profileId')
        ;
        $res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $res;
    }
```