# Optimize DQL with double join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have such a structure: single profile can attend do several studies and for each study there is `statute` field which is foreign key to `study_statute`. In HTML in each row I need to show information for profile: profile.name, profile.study.field, profile.study.statute. I've done this using

```
$profileRepository->findAll()
```

but it generates to many queries and I want to optimize. At the moment there is query fetching profiles , for each profile ask for studies and for each study ask for statute name. So if there are 2 profiles and each profile attends to 2 studies I have

1 (list)
+1 (study list for profile #1)
+2 (study names for each of above studies)
+1 (study list for profile #2)
+2 (study names for each of above studies)
queries.

How to optimize this?

In plain PHP I'd do: fetch big table for all profiles joined with studies and study names and parse it to multidimensional arrays, f.e. `$profile[1]['studies'][1]['name']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dql [fetch join](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins):

```php
$profiles = $em->createQuery('select p, stu, sta from YourBundleName:Profile p join p.studies stu join stu.statute sta')
    ->getResult();
```

The result would be the same as if you would use `findAll` except one thing. All related entities would have been fetched. If you access the "study" or "statute" Doctrine does not need to `lazy load` the association with another query.